# Как зациклить данный код в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, turtle

День добрый! Не могу реализовать цикл из-за недостаточности знаний в сфере программирования. 
Хочу реализовать задачу: создать цикл, который отрисует 5 квадратов в модуле Turtle.

Помогите доработать, чтобы был один цикл, который делает все то же, что у меня записано в пяти. Заранее спасибо!

```
import turtle
turtle.shape('turtle')

m = 0
n = 0
k = 0
l = 0
o = 0
while k  < 4: 
    k+=1
    turtle.fd(30)
    turtle.lt(90)
turtle.goto(-5,-5)
while l < 4:
    l+=1
    turtle.fd(40)
    turtle.lt(90)
turtle.goto(-10,-10)
while m < 4:
    m+=1
    turtle.fd(50)
    turtle.lt(90)
turtle.goto(-15,-15)
while n < 4:
    n+=1
    turtle.fd(60)
    turtle.lt(90)
turtle.goto(-20,-20) 
while o < 4:
    o+=1
    turtle.fd(70)
    turtle.lt(90)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно так:

```
import turtle
turtle.shape('turtle')

for l in range(5):
    for k in range(4):
        turtle.fd(30+l*10)
        turtle.lt(90)
    if l!=5:
        turtle.goto(-5*(l+1), -5*(l+1))
```